# Inquiry about InputStream "System.in"

Tags: java, io, nio, bufferedinputstream

I would like to achieve the following:

```
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
        int c = 0;
        while((c=is.read())!=-1)
        Files.copy(is, path3, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Hoewver it gets stuck in waiting System.in forever..
Any workaround for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can't block at the constructor. Do you mean at `is.read()`?

Comment: It's blocking trying to read from the console.. did you key-in any input?

Comment: Did you press `return` at the console? Before that, no input is seen by `System.in`.

Comment: If you want reaction at each keypress, `System.in` is not the way to go. You need AWT events.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Therefore something like that will never terminate in anyhow? no flags no typing -1 as an input nothing?  Files.copy(System.in, path3, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); where path3 is a valid and existing path/file

Comment: Did you type ctrl/z or ctrl/d (system dependent) at the console to provide the EOS? Your code won't terminate until it gets one. However your code makes no sense anyway. You are reading one character from System.in, throwing it away, then copying the entire stream, then repeating until the character read is -1. What is the actual objective here?

Comment: @EJP just preparing for the OCPJP7. and thinking of possible tricky questions.

Comment: @EJP However with ctrl+d works! it was just what I was looking for! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to stop reading on new line or carriage return or end of stream, you may try-

```
do {

    try {

        c = is.read();

        // Do something

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

} while ((c != -1) & (c != '\n') & (c != '\r'));
```